# My subclipse colors don't work

Tags: eclipse, svn

This is probably a simple issue for some subclipse guru.  My decorator colors don't work in eclipse.  I'm guessing that some plugin I have is interfering with it somehow.  I'm on the current public release of ganymede.  Going to the fonts and colors option area lets me change the decorator text color, but I get no effect in the project explorer.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not important any more, but the decorator issue came down to using the correct view.  The "project" view and the "file" view look extremely similar, but the decorators work correctly in one and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using KDE on Linux? There is a known bug if you use the gtk-qt-engine to make GTK programs (like Eclipse) look more like KDE apps. If this gtk theming engine is active the text colors in views don't work. This is a common problem for mylyn users.

Comment: I'm using Vista 64 with 32 bit eclipse.  I've since noticed that the colors DO work in certain perspectives.  I must have some plugin that's misbehaving.